# Pausar o programa durante a execução de um código c#

Tags: c#, thread

Tô com dúvida na utilização de threads, eu quero que, em um determinado tempo, o programa pare de responder e só volte quando eu determinar...

Exemplo:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Pausa();

// Executa código

System.Threading.Thread.VoltaDnv();
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: Se entendi bem, você deseja travar o programa. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Se ele vai estar parado como ele vai saber quando voltar?

Comment: Me parece que você quer fazer algum controle de concorrência... Se for isso, existem alternativas prontas e bem pensadas para isso.

Comment: Ele vai saber quando voltar quando passar pro System.Threading.Thread.VoltaDnv(); que é quando termina as linhas de código do // Executa código

Comment: É assim, ao clicar no botão, o programa vai travar e ser redimensionado, e depois de ser redimensionado, vai destravar

Comment: Se está pausado, como vai passar por ali? É melhor explicar o que deseja, porque parece que este é o mecanismo errado para a tarefa.

Comment: Quando eu vou baixar algum arquivo, o programa não trava e destrava quando termina de baixar? Claro, sem ser no método assíncrono. Entendeu?

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta colocando um exemplo, assim ficará mais simples de entender.

Comment: Você está querendo fazer isso da forma errada.. isso de pausar para fazer uma outra tarefa... tem que ser um assíncrono.
Qual o problema de usar async? ou Background worker que seja?